# How to use Detect Intent(Text) in Django Python?

Tags: python, django, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm creating a chatbot with Dialogflow and Django-python. Right now, I already created an agent in Dialogflow, already have a Django app, used ngork, and other necessary stuffs except for connecting Dialogflow to Django app's fulfillment/and calling APIs.

I stumbled across this documentation https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2 and successfully did all the steps needed. In the last part of the documentation, it seems that what I finally need to do is use the dialogflow detect intent text , so I copied it and put it into my Django app(*views.py*).

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.

    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversation."""

    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
            text=text, language_code=language_code)

        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

        response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        print('=' * 20)
        print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
        print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
            response.query_result.intent.display_name,
            response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
        print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
            response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
```

Now, I don't know what to do next. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use it or how it exactly works as I am still new to this. I already searched for answers in the web but I didn't get a clear understanding about it and got overwhelmed a bit(as it seems that there is a lot to do with this). I hope I could get an example or step by step procedure about it.

Comment: I've flagged your question as too broad, since it's unclear what exactly you already know and have. Basically, you'll want to save some results from this piece of code in your database, and/or return results from this view to a template for rendering into a HTML page.

Comment: @9769953 Sorry, but what I understood from what you just said, is that this piece of code(detect_intext_text), is used to take the user text/result from the agent(dialogflow), then pass it to a template/html page in my Django-app?

What I thought about this code(detect intent text), is that it will connect Dialogflow agent to Django app fulfillment and will be able to call APIs.

Comment: It's not passing anything, since there is no return. Django views would return something at least. But this isn't a proper Django view in the first place, since it doesn't take a `request` as its first argument (or `proper_id` is really badly named). But is this `detect_intent_texts` function in your list of URLs in the first place? How is it called?

Comment: @9769953 OP have not provided django code at all, `detect_intent_texts` function is being used to call dialogflow and get result from it. in my answer i have tried to explain how to get request in django view then call dialogflow and return the result from the view.

Comment: @sid8491 I know; that's the problem. I think the OP is still figuring out how Django practically works. But it's unclear without further context.

Comment: @9769953 Hello, I'm sorry that I didn't include my whole django code and caused a confusion. Yes, I already have set the views.py with import dialogflow and httpResponse. And the only thing inside my views.py is that detect_intent_text. Also, I have my urls set in my urls.py .

Comment: @jaccMultiverse then the answer should solve your problem. try that and let us know if you encounter more issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you know the basic functionalities of Django, and you are using v2 of Dialogflow.

You need to pass the user text request from front-end to the `views.py`. YOu will get it in `request` object, then you need to extract it.
After extracting the text, you need to call dialogflow's `detect_intent()` function with `text` and `session_id` (text requests with same session_id will be treated as same part of conversation).

Also, you would need to get a json file from GCP console in order to authenticate the dialogflow request. You can read more about that [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup).

Here is sample code which you can extend according to your use:

```
import dialogflow
from django.http import HttpResponse

def your_view(request):
    text = request.POST.get("text_request")
    session_id = 'some_session_id'
    res = detect_intent(text)
    return HttpResponse(res)

def detect_intent(text, session_id):
    language_code = 'en'
    project_id = 'your_dialogflow_project_id'
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path_to_your_json_file'

    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name,
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
    return response.query_result.fulfillment_text
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't that view still return something (instead of `None`)?

Comment: yes it should, i wrote code to explain how you would get text in view and call Dialogflow. django and view parts i have omitted.

Comment: Well, no, you didn't omit the Django view, because `your_view` is pretty clearly a Django view. You now have half a view, returning nothing, which may be part of what the OP is struggling with.

Comment: @sid8491  Hello, sorry if I didn't mentioned this before(as I don't know if it's important), but I also use facebook messenger for the end-users to communicate with the bot. The webhooks are already set and is connected to the dialogflow agent. So, the whole process will be, user chats to messenger>then dialoglow will query it and look for the intent>then the fulfillment part which calls for RESTful apis in the backend(Django). I don't know the whole process in the fulfillment part and how I can call the apis and return it to the dialogflow agent to answer the users in fb messenger.

Comment: @sid8491 I also have done the GCP authentication, it was part of the documentation that I linked in my post which I followed.

Comment: @jaccMultiverse you're asking too broad questions, try to break them into smalled ones and ask here. get the functionality done in smaller chunks and tie them up. also if this answer helped you then accept and upvote. ask more questions for different problems.

Comment: @sid8491 Ok, I'll try to narrow down the problem and I'll post a question later. But one more thing, after reading the documentations, and your answer, the detect intent function is used for determining what the user has requested and which actions to take?

Comment: `session_client.detect_intent()` function of class dialogflow will take session and query input, then call dialogflow to check which intent it matches. it will return multiple things like intent matched, entities found in the text, fulfillment texts etc. all those thing will be done according to your dialogflow agent which you will make on dialogflow.com console

Comment: @jaccMultiverse upvote the answer if it was helpful, raise more questions for different questions, let us know if you have more doubt in this one. happy to help :)

Comment: @sid8491 Hello again, sorry but I still can't upvote answers due to my low reputation as I am still new, but I accepted it. I'll upvote this once i get the minimum rep for voting. I'm trying to fix an error right now in the authentication of servicce account. Once I solved this I'll be back asking more questions, and thanks for the help!